# Spark maven dependency breaks down sprint-boot application

Tags: maven, apache-spark, spring-boot, apache-spark-2.0

I have a spring-boot application with Swing GUI. It just work! But as soon as I add **spark 2.0** dependency to the **pom.xml** file it shows the following error message during start up and will not start!

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/ehsun7b/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.7/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/ehsun7b/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.21/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.1.RELEASE)

2016-10-21 00:02:23.795  INFO 1642 --- [           main] edu.mfldclin.mcrf.vakilabad.Application  : Starting Application on Ehsuns-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 1642 (/Users/ehsun7b/NetBeansProjects/vakilabad/target/classes started by ehsun7b in /Users/ehsun7b/NetBeansProjects/vakilabad)
2016-10-21 00:02:23.797  INFO 1642 --- [           main] edu.mfldclin.mcrf.vakilabad.Application  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-10-21 00:02:23.839  INFO 1642 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@67c27493: startup date [Fri Oct 21 00:02:23 MYT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-10-21 00:02:24.290  INFO 1642 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-10-21 00:02:25.650  INFO 1642 --- [           main] e.m.mcrf.vakilabad.log.LogService        : LogService init.
2016-10-21 00:02:25.767  INFO 1642 --- [           main] e.mfldclin.mcrf.vakilabad.log.LogFrame   : Adding LogFrame instance to the LogMonitors of LogService: edu.mfldclin.mcrf.vakilabad.log.LogFrame[frame0,0,2,511x390,invalid,hidden,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=Log since 2016-10-21T00:02:25.750,resizable,normal,defaultCloseOperation=DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,0,22,511x368,invalid,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true]
2016-10-21 00:02:25.897  WARN 1642 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.info-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
2016-10-21 00:02:25.897  INFO 1642 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2016-10-21 00:02:25.902  INFO 1642 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2016-10-21 00:02:25.906 ERROR 1642 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Bean Validation API is on the classpath but no implementation could be found

Action:

Add an implementation, such as Hibernate Validator, to the classpath
```

This the dependency that I add:

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am seeing in `spark-core_2.11-2.0.1.jar\META-INF\DEPENDENCIES` and there is:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// Transitive dependencies of this project determined from the
// maven pom organized by organization.
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

Spark Project Core


From: 'an unknown organization'
...
...
  - Bean Validation API (http://beanvalidation.org) javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final
    License: The Apache Software License, Version 2.0  (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt)
```

and with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` spring probably see this dependency on classpath and try to find implementation of [Java specification for Bean Validation](http://beanvalidation.org). (Some interesting reading for [spring validation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation)).

*In my opinion it is because spark uses `jersey` as a way how to show us information of job status and so on [jersey bean-validation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html) - but I am not quite sure about this statement.*

But you can fix this issue by providing implementation of `Bean Validation` - just add dependency of implementation to maven.

**Hibernate-validator**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

or much more quicker ([source](http://carinae.net/2010/06/benchmarking-hibernate-validator-and-apache-beanvalidation-the-two-jsr-303-implementations/)) **Apache BeanValidation**.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.bval/bval-jsr303 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.bval</groupId>
    <artifactId>bval-jsr303</artifactId>
    <version>0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

---

**SOLUTION is in the comments! (exclusion of validation API)**

Comment: yesterday I tried to add hibernate validator and it didn't solve the issue, let me try apache bval and see how.

Comment: Didn't help much:

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.info-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is

Comment: Hmm that's weird. Try to exclude validation, but I think it is better to solve this with BeanValidator, but you can try something like this for `spark-core` exlude dependency:        `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>`

Comment: It solve the issue for the moment, I hope this exclusion does not effect anything in spark API. Thanks